Jacoco @Generated annotation is not excluding class with methods having anonymous class
I am using following this article to exclude any custom class where I dont want to write test cases
https://www.baeldung.com/jacoco-report-exclude annotation to exclude class from jacoco coverage.
I found jacoco looks for Generated word in annotation and exclude the annotation class.
https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/822/files
So went ahead and created following annoation:-
@Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport {
}

I wanted to exclude following class from coverage report
@ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport
class UserRepoImpl {

public long getCountById(long userId){

 UserFetcher fether =
 // this shows up as red in jacoco report coverage, ideally it shouldn't as i have already excluded the whole class using ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport annotation.
new UserFetcher  public void init(long userId){
         //initialise user 
    }
}; 
}


public void updateUser(User user){
//update the user
}
}


Annoymous class should automatically get excluded from jacoco coverage report but its not happening and showing 0% coverage.

I found the answer, here is what you can try :-
As ElementType.TYPE_USE in your annotation (this will work for jdk 8,+)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
public @interface ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport {
} 

and tried this, but it didn't work, I don't know why its not excluding anonymous class.
@ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport
class UserRepoImpl {

public long getCountById(long userId){

 UserFetcher fether =
new @ExcludeFromJacocoGeneratedReport UserFetcher  public void init(long userId){
         //initialise user 
    }
}; 
}


public void updateUser(User user){
//update the user
}
}



To exclude anonymous class I had to manually exclude using *$*.* in my build.xml as
<exclude name = "**/**/*$*.*"/>

Run the report again and you are good to go.
